# cancel loading operation started by loadUrl() method

Tags: android

How can I cancel a loading operation in WebView started by mWebView.loadUrl( "my_url" ) method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That'd be through [`mWebView.stopLoading()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#stopLoading%28%29)